# SQL - How to transpose several columns?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in an IBM DB2 database; let's call it table_1. It looks a bit like this:

| customer | info | offer_type_a_sales | offer_type_b_sales | offer_type_c_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | X | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| BB | Y | 0 | 10 | 15 |
| CC | X | 20 | 0 | 30 |

What I'd like to do is transpose the offer type columns to create a single column flagging offer type and a single column showing sales. Does anyone know how best to do this please?

The desired output should look like this:

| customer | info | offer_type | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | X | a | 10 |
| AA | X | b | 20 |
| AA | X | c | 30 |
| BB | Y | b | 10 |
| BB | Y | c | 15 |
| CC | X | a | 20 |
| CC | X | c | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to `unpivot` but here's an alternative solution using `union`.

```
select customer, info, 'a' as offer_type, offer_type_a_sales as sales from table_1
union
select customer, info, 'b', offer_type_b_sales from table_1
union 
select customer, info, 'c', offer_type_c_sales from table_1
```

| customer | info | offer_type | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | X | a | 10 |
| AA | X | b | 20 |
| AA | X | c | 30 |
| BB | Y | a | 0 |
| BB | Y | b | 10 |
| BB | Y | c | 15 |
| CC | X | a | 20 |
| CC | X | b | 0 |
| CC | X | c | 30 |

If you don't want the zero rows then add a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are looking for is the opposite of a pivot operation. I prepared an `MSSQL` example for you.

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this

```
/*Data Creation*/
Create Table #talbe_1(
    customer Nvarchar(max),
    info Nvarchar(max),
    offer_type_a_sales int,
    offer_type_b_sales int,
    offer_type_c_sales int
)

insert into #talbe_1 (customer, info, offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales)
Values ('AA', 'X', 10, 20, 30)
insert into #talbe_1 (customer, info, offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales)
Values ('BB', 'Y', 0, 10, 15)
insert into #talbe_1 (customer, info, offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales)
Values ('CC', 'X', 20, 0, 30)
/*Data Creation*/

/*Solution*/
SELECT customer, info, (CASE offertype When 'offer_type_a_sales' Then 'a' When 'offer_type_b_sales' Then 'b' When 'offer_type_c_sales' Then 'c' Else '-' End) as 'offertype', sales
FROM
    (SELECT customer, info, offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales FROM #talbe_1) p
UNPIVOT
   (sales FOR offertype IN (offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales)
) AS unpvt
WHERE sales > 0
/*Solution*/

Drop Table #talbe_1
```

It is necessary to give column headers during the `UNPIVOT` process. I used `CASE` `WHEN` because it returns values with the names in these column headers.

Result:

| customer | info | offertype | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | X | a | 10 |
| AA | X | b | 20 |
| AA | X | c | 30 |
| BB | Y | b | 10 |
| BB | Y | c | 15 |
| CC | X | a | 20 |
| CC | X | c | 30 |

The union example is also good but you might want to use this one.

If the columns come dynamically and are not fixed; (offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales, offer_type_d_sales, offer_type_e_sales etc.) If there is a structure in this way, you can take it into EXEC and give the places corresponding to the column parts externally. Additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 doesn't support the `UNPIVOT` clause, but there is an alternative solution.

```
WITH MYTAB (customer,   info,   offer_type_a_sales, offer_type_b_sales, offer_type_c_sales)
AS
(
VALUES
  ('AA',    'X',    10, 20, 30)
, ('BB',    'Y',    0,  10, 15)
, ('CC',    'X',    20, 0,  30)
)
SELECT
  T.customer
, T.info
, V.offer_type
, V.offer_type_sales
FROM MYTAB T
, TABLE 
(
  VALUES
    ('a', T.offer_type_a_sales)
  , ('b', T.offer_type_b_sales)
  , ('c', T.offer_type_c_sales)
) V (offer_type, offer_type_sales)
```

| CUSTOMER | INFO | OFFER_TYPE | OFFER_TYPE_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | X | a | 10 |
| AA | X | b | 20 |
| AA | X | c | 30 |
| BB | Y | a | 0 |
| BB | Y | b | 10 |
| BB | Y | c | 15 |
| CC | X | a | 20 |
| CC | X | b | 0 |
| CC | X | c | 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UPmGsLAZ)